# Inserting data from one excel file to another using Python openpxyl

Tags: python, excel, datetime, automation, openpyxl

The columns in the first excel file is as follows:

1. CountryID
2. CountryName
3. CapitalCity
4. Population
5. Processed Date
6. Current Date
7. OfficialLanguage
8. Currency
9. GDP
10. TourismRating

(PS. Date format is in YYYY/MM/DD)

The columns in the template file is as follows:

1. ID (A2)
2. Name (C2)
3. Capital (D2)
4. Population (E2)
5. Processed Date (F2)
6. Current Date (G2)
7. Language (H2)
8. Currency (I2)
9. GDP (J2)
10. TourismRating (K2)

CountryID has to go into B3, A3 must be empty. As the ID heading column is merged by A2 and B2 and becomes just A2 so that this column is split into A3 and B3. And the Date format for cells F2 and G2 must be in DD MMM YYYY eg. 19 Jan 2024.

The data from the first excel file needs to be exported into the template file according to their corresponding column names using python. This code needs to work such that each time I drop a file, it uses the template and populates and gets saved separately. So I have 3 files, the original, the same template and the new file.

I tried the following code: It works, but does not export the data correctly. Please see following code and pictures of the first and template excel file.

```
import openpyxl as xl
from datetime import datetime

# Function to convert date format
def convert_date_format(date_value):
    if date_value is None:
        return None
    elif isinstance(date_value, datetime):
        return date_value.strftime("%d %b %Y")
    else:
        try:
            date_obj = datetime.strptime(date_value, "%Y/%m/%d")
            return date_obj.strftime("%d %b %Y")
        except (ValueError, TypeError):
            return date_value

# opening the source excel file 
filename = "SOURCE EXCEL FILE.XLSX"
wb1 = xl.load_workbook(filename) 
ws1 = wb1.worksheets[0] 

# Unprotect the source worksheet if it's protected
if ws1.protection.sheet:
    ws1.unprotect()

# opening the destination excel file  
filename1 = "Template.xlsx"
wb2 = xl.load_workbook(filename1) 
template_ws = wb2.active  # Define template_ws

# calculate total number of rows and  
# columns in source excel file 
mr = ws1.max_row 
mc = ws1.max_column 

# Map column names
column_mapping = {
    'CountryID': 'A2',
    'CountryName': 'C2',
    'CapitalCity': 'D2',
    'Population': 'E2',
    'Processed Date': 'F2',
    'Current date': 'G2',
    'Official Language': 'H2',
    'Currency': 'I2',
    'GDP': 'J2',
    'TourismRating': 'K2'
}

# Loop through each row in the source worksheet
for row in range(2, mr + 1):
    # Extract data from source worksheet based on column mapping
    data = [ws1[column_mapping[col]].value for col in column_mapping.keys()]

    # Convert date formats
    data[4] = convert_date_format(data[4])  # Processed Date
    data[5] = convert_date_format(data[5])  # Current date

    # Split the "Account" column
    account_parts = str(data[0]).split(" ")
    data[0] = account_parts[1] if len(account_parts) > 1 else None

    # Append data to template worksheet
    template_ws.append(data)

# Save the modified template
wb2.save(r"Provide the desired path to save the modified template")
```

Here are some screenshots to help:

First file:

[image: First file]

Template File]:

[image: Template File]

Comment: I don't understand this sentence ***As the ID heading column is merged by A2 and B2 and becomes just A2 so that this column is split into A3 and B3*** . There is a 'CountryID' in the source, your example it's '10000' which is converted by the  `# Split the "Account" column` section. There is no "Account" column and the first part of the code attempts to split the value on space which doesn't exist in the value thus resulting in that element being set to `None` by your code. Openpyxl append starts from column A, so if you need to, pad the list. Maybe a what you do expect screenshot would help.